# Rigify does not apply on the metarig with custom bones properly

Tags: rigging, bones, customization, rigify

Right now I'm stuck. When I press the "Generate Rig" button Blender proceeds but it add's only the bottom move thingy widget to the rig, nothing else. It's a custom rig with custom bones applied on the vertebrae of the spine. In addition I don't get any error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have any "rig types" set for the legs, arms etc.
How did you make this meta rig?
Looking at the spine, it seems like you did some modifications to the default human metarig.

Comment: Correct, the rig types were missing, thank you!
I took the human meta rig as an example to build in addition to that I added 24 custom bones as Vertebraes for the entire spine. Each vertebrae or "spinebone" is a 3D scan of a real vertebrae. I used the script "Orient Custom Shape" for the Object to Armature transformation + allignment.